# Extract Code between two different new line strings

Tags: bash, awk, sed, extract

So I have been struggling with this for a few days now, trying solutions with `grep`, `sed` and `awk` all of which work to some extent but not to my exact requirements. Below is the data I am working with. I need to extract, 2nd prize the data between each new line `--------` string, or first prize between each domain in the list.

I need for each domain to extract it's particular database details.

```
somedomain.co.za

\---------------------------

Database name   somedb_db1

Full    somepassword

Login   somelogin_1

Read only       somepassword

Read/Write      somepassword

Server name     some.host.net

somedomain.org.za

\---------------------------

Database name   somedb_db1

Full    somepassword

Login   somelogin

Read only       somepassword

Read/Write      somepassword

Server name     some.host.net

somedomain.co.za

\---------------------------

Database name   somedb_db1

Full    somepassword

Login   somelogin_1

Read only       somepassword

Read/Write      somepassword

Server name     some.host.net

somedomain.co.za

\---------------------------

Server name     some.host.net

Database name   somedb_wp

Full    somepassword

Login   somelogin_4

Read/Write      somepassword

Read only       somepassword

Server name     some.host.net

Read/Write      somepassword

Read only       somepassword

Login   somelogin_3

Full    somepassword

Database name   somedb_db3

somedomain.co.za

\---------------------------
```

Comment: Can you give also expected result?

Comment: Where are the "prizes" ?

Comment: for each domain the result should be as below: 

somedomain.co.za

---------------------------

Server name some.host.net

Database name somedb_wp

Full somepassword

Login somelogin_4

Read/Write somepassword

Read only somepassword

Server name some.host.net

Read/Write somepassword

Read only somepassword

Login somelogin_3

Full somepassword

Database name somedb_db3

Comment: as for "prizes" lots of street cred and that feeling of joy you feel when you help someone..?

Comment: prize 1=what he want the most, prize 2= is less desirable but also ok (I think) . Please add the clarifications in your question and use `{}` to mark input/output blocks.

Comment: A `while-loop` (slow for large input files) and `awk` (best) will be able to handle blocks of data belonging together. Please post what you already have tried with `awk` and where you are stuck.

Comment: @WalterA Oh, cheers. The way it was worded made it sound like the prizes were part of the data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with awk to get entry for each DB properties with domain info. 
Is this the requirement?

```
awk 'NR==nr{
    next
}
NF==1{
    nr=NR+1;
    dmn=$1;
    i=1;
    next
}
dmn"@"$1"@"i in a{
    i++
}
{
    a[dmn"@"$1"@"i];
    b[dmn","i]=b[dmn","i]","$0
}
END {
    for ( i in b) print i""b[i]
}' file
```

Assume no empty line in `File`.

I/P:

```
v.co.za
\---------------------------
Database name   somedb_db1
Full    somepassword
Login   somelogin_1
Read only       somepassword
Read/Write      somepassword
Server name     some.host.net
w.org.za
\---------------------------
Database name   somedb_db1
Full    somepassword
Login   somelogin
Read only       somepassword
Read/Write      somepassword
Server name     some.host.net
z.co.za
\---------------------------
Database name   somedb_db1
Full    somepassword
Login   somelogin_1
Read only       somepassword
Read/Write      somepassword
Server name     some.host.net
y.co.za
\---------------------------
Server name     some.host.net
Database name   somedb_wp
Full    somepassword
Login   somelogin_4
Read/Write      somepassword
Read only       somepassword
Server name     some.host.net
Read/Write      somepassword
Read only       somepassword
Login   somelogin_3
Full    somepassword
Database name   somedb_db3
x.co.za
\---------------------------
```

O/P:

```
v.co.za,1,Database name   somedb_db1,Full    somepassword,Login   somelogin_1,Read only       somepassword,Read/Write      somepassword,Server name     some.host.net
w.org.za,1,Database name   somedb_db1,Full    somepassword,Login   somelogin,Read only       somepassword,Read/Write      somepassword,Server name     some.host.net
y.co.za,1,Server name     some.host.net,Database name   somedb_wp,Full    somepassword,Login   somelogin_4,Read/Write      somepassword,Read only       somepassword
y.co.za,2,Server name     some.host.net,Read/Write      somepassword,Read only       somepassword,Login   somelogin_3,Full    somepassword,Database name   somedb_db3
z.co.za,1,Database name   somedb_db1,Full    somepassword,Login   somelogin_1,Read only       somepassword,Read/Write      somepassword,Server name     some.host.net
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this question rather vague, but I think you might be looking for something like this `awk` script:

```
/.*\.(co|org)\.za/ { print RECORD; RECORD = $0; next }
{ RECORD = RECORD "\n" $0 }
END { print RECORD }
```

Of course, you will probably want to do something other than simply print the records.

Comment: im not really sure how to clarify the question any further, but I will try. So the data contains a domain.tld and the next line contains dash dash dash etc. Below the dash dash dash will be database details for that particular domain. I need to extract the domain.tld and its particular db details. It will be contained between the lines, domain.tld dash dash dash etc next domain.tld. Hope that provides clarity?

Comment: Well, I found your repeated use of `somedomain.co.za` confusing. Is that supposed to be one particular domain, or do you really mean something like `.*\.co\.za`. I assumed the latter. If the former, the answer may be simpler.

Comment: The TLDs will all be different. You will note that there is one org.za TLD in my sample data. This is why I cannot match on TLD.

Comment: I have updated my answer accordingly. You might have to change the regular expression to match all the domains in the file.